# Why does DataGrid not show new columns from DataTable when added in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm adding/removing columns and rows to the DataTable in my code behind. In my xaml code I have a DataGrid which ItemsSource is bound to the DataTable, but the DataGrid does not show new or removed columns. The rows are working fine.

Here is my code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
    this.Table = new DataTable();
}

private DataTable _Table;
public DataTable Table
{
    get { return this._Table; }
    set { this._Table = value; }
}

public void AddColumn()
{
    this.Table.Columns.Add("ColumnTest");
}

public void AddRow()
{
    this.Table.Rows.Add();
}
```

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgdMain" 
          Grid.Column="1"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table.DefaultView}">
</DataGrid>
```

The methods to add a column or row are called by a button click event. If I added some columns before binding the columns are shown correctly.

Comment: Try `ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"`. This assumes you have correctly set the views `DataContext`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't by default. You will have to add any new columns yourself:

```
public void AddColumn()
{
    this.Table.Columns.Add("ColumnTest");
    dgdMain.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Binding = new Binding("ColumnTest"), Header = "ColumnTest" });
}
```

The columns are only auto-generated when you set the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid. Any new columns that you add to the `DataTable` dynamically after this are not added to the `DataGrid` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrids don't monitor schema changes on underlying datatable datasources. If you want the datagrid to update, change your AddColumn method and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your code-behind. If you move this code out from code-behind to a ViewModel (highly recommended) then you'll also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged there.

```
public void AddColumn()
{
    this.Table.Columns.Add("ColumnTest");
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Table));
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName) => 
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Comment: What `CallerMemberNameAttribute` do in that call to `OnPropertyChanged();`? Raising PropertyChanged for "AddColumn" seems unhelpful. And raising it for "Table" won't help (I just tested that).